# Building binary tree using Java Stream. Is it possible in Java Stream sorting while reduce?

Tags: sorting, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I want to build a [Huffman tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) from input string using Java Stream.

This is how I do it right now.

Class MyNode with all needed Constructors:

```
public static class MyNode {
    Character value;
    MyNode left;
    MyNode right;
    long freq;
    ...
}
```

Reading a line and getting List of MyNodes:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scan.next();
List<MyNode> listOfNodes = input.chars().boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) 
            .entrySet()
            .stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .map(x -> new MyNode((char)x.getKey().intValue(), x.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This `while` loop I want to replace with something from Stream:

```
while (listOfNodes.size() > 1) {
        MyNode first = listOfNodes.get(0);
        MyNode second = listOfNodes.get(1);
        listOfNodes.remove(first);
        listOfNodes.remove(second);
        listOfNodes.add(new MyNode(first.freq + second.freq, first, second));
        listOfNodes.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(MyNode::getFreq));
    }
```

In while loop I build tree like this [image: while loop pic]

The first idea was to use Stream reduce, but then I need to sort resulting list after every reduce.

Comment: Please post an example using a loop, because your picture explains nothing and English doesn't convey the meaning of what you want. This *"I know, that reduce does not work like this, but this is the idea. Thanks a lot."* Adds nothing to the question. What are you asking?

Comment: Indeed, this isn't very clear.  Given that the sort could move/replace the "current" element of the reduction, it's not clear what you would expect to happen next.

Comment: Streams operations are intended to be applied on all elements of the sequence... Then I would answer: no don't try something like that on streams.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I rewrote the question. Sorry for poor wording

Comment: You do not need to sort the entire `listOfNodes` in each list iteration. Since the list is already sorted, use [`Collections.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-) to find the right insertion position, so the list stays sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a task that benefits from using the Stream API. Still, there are ways to improve it.

Sorting the entire list just for the sake of inserting a single element, bear an unnecessary overhead. Since the list is sorted to begin with, you can use binary search to efficiently find the correct insertion position so that the list stays sorted:

```
while(listOfNodes.size() > 1) {
    MyNode first = listOfNodes.remove(0), second = listOfNodes.remove(0);
    MyNode newNode = new MyNode(first.freq + second.freq, first, second);
    int pos = Collections.binarySearch(listOfNodes, newNode,
                                       Comparator.comparingLong(MyNode::getFreq));
    listOfNodes.add(pos<0? -pos-1: pos, newNode);
}
```

Note that you could make this code more efficient by reversing the order so that you will remove from the end of the list (which will be an `ArrayList` in practice).

But the better alternative is to use a data structure which is sorted to begin with, e.g.

```
PriorityQueue<MyNode> queueOfNodes = input.chars().boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) 
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(x -> new MyNode((char)x.getKey().intValue(), x.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
        () -> new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingLong(MyNode::getFreq))));

MyNode result = queueOfNodes.remove();
while(!queueOfNodes.isEmpty()) {
    MyNode second = queueOfNodes.remove();
    queueOfNodes.add(new MyNode(result.freq + second.freq, result, second));
    result = queueOfNodes.remove();
}
```